# Using a paid Zoom account to start a meeting and pass host privileges; can I leave the meeting and have it still benefit from my account's privileges?

Tags: zoom.us

A friend of mine has a lot of Zoom calls to co-ordinate, and they would like to be able to pass their host controls without disrupting their own use of Zoom at the same time.

So if they hand their host privileges to someone else, can they leave the meeting and have it still personally benefit from their account's privileges like longer duration limits? And does the other person (who has had host privileges passed to them) need to have a paid account too for that to work correctly?

They have access to both the web client and the either app, however I am aware neither app is on topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Whoever you pass the meeting to will inherit your paid privileges, or lack thereof.

According to the online documentation:

> As the host, you can assign the host controls to another user and leave the meeting. This allows the meeting to continue without you, and the assigned user to have host control over the meeting.
>
> **If the original host is a Licensed user**, the meeting will continue to run for an unlimited time, even if the new host is a free or basic user.
>
> **If the original host is a Free or Basic user**, the meeting will be limited to the 40 minute duration, even if the new host is a Licensed user.
>
> -- ["Passing Host Controls and Leaving the Meeting"](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362573-Pass-Host-Controls-and-Leave-the-Meeting)